# Calculating Routes: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double

Tags: r

I have a df of start and end coordinates. I'm trying to calculate the full route for a small portion of the df, about 300 trips. ggmap route function begins but runs into an error after about 12 route calculations. The error is **(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**. How can I fix this in the code? I have a csv of the data in the link below for anyone to test with.

The overall end goal is a product like this http://flowingdata.com/2014/02/05/where-people-run/ that visualises all routes taken.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
feb_14 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smitty1788/Personal-Website/master/dl/CaBi_Feb_2017.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


start<-c(feb_14[1:300, 14])
dest<-c(feb_14[1:300, 15])


routes <- tibble(
  start,
  dest)

calculationroute <- function(startingpoint, stoppoint) {
  route(from = startingpoint,
        to = stoppoint,
        mode = 'bicycling',
        structure = "route")}

calculatedroutes <- mapply(calculationroute,
                           startingpoint = routes$start,
                           stoppoint = routes$dest,
                           SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(names(calculatedroutes), function(x) {
  cbind.data.frame(route=x, calculatedroutes[[x]], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})) -> long_routes
```

**This is the Error**

```
Error in route(from = startingpoint, to = stoppoint, mode = "bicycling",  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Called from: route(from = startingpoint, to = stoppoint, mode = "bicycling", 
    structure = "route")
Browse[1]> 
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(names(calculatedroutes), function(x) {
+   cbind.data.frame(route=x, calculatedroutes[[x]], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
+ })) -> long_routes
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but doesn't `route()` require character input? I can read the start address for example using: `start<-as.character(feb_14[1:10, 6])`. This produces the calculatedroutes but I am confused what the goal is of the long_routes object.

Comment: I converted Lat/Long coordinates to a character in columns 14 and 15. I forgot to add StringsAsFactors = FALSE in the read.csv. The goal end product is something like this http://flowingdata.com/2014/02/05/where-people-run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was with the Google API. I was hitting the per second rate limit. The simple fix was adding a Sys.Sleep to slow down the call rate.

```
calculationroute <- function(startingpoint, stoppoint) {
 Sys.sleep(1)
  route(from = startingpoint,
        to = stoppoint,
        mode = "bicycling",
        structure = "route")}
```